# Raplace value between 2 files with value from file2 (second column) when there is match in 1 column of both files

Tags: awk

I have 2 csv files (they large and they dont have qual number of rows). Here I present only example files which have the same number of rows):

File1:

```
NC_008689 2 NA NA NA NA 
NC_002670 3 NA NA NA 186 
NC_002671 9 NA NA NA 107 
NC_009382 25 9 15 NA 100 
NC_003977 45 92 535 NA 492685
```

File2:

```
NC_008689   Siphoviridae,Biseptimavirus,Staphylococcus virus 108PVL
NC_002670   Siphoviridae,,Lactococcus phage bIL311
NC_002671   Siphoviridae,,Lactococcus phage bIL312
NC_009382   Myoviridae,Peduovirus,Ralstonia virus RSA1
NC_003977   Hepadnaviridae,Orthohepadnavirus,Hepatitis B virus
```

Desired output:

```
Siphoviridae,Biseptimavirus,Staphylococcus virus 108PVL 2   NA  NA  NA  NA
Siphoviridae,,Lactococcus phage bIL311  3   NA  NA  NA  186
Siphoviridae,,Lactococcus phage bIL312  9   NA  NA  NA  107
Myoviridae,Peduovirus,Ralstonia virus RSA1  25  9   15  NA  100
Hepadnaviridae,Orthohepadnavirus,Hepatitis B virus2 45  92  535 NA  492685
```

I tried:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { F2[$1]=$2 ; next } $1 in F2 {$1 = F2[$1] ; print } ' File2 File1
```

but as a result I have:

```
Siphoviridae,Biseptimavirus,Staphylococcus 2 NA NA NA NA
Siphoviridae,,Lactococcus 3 NA NA NA 186
Siphoviridae,,Lactococcus 9 NA NA NA 107
Myoviridae,Peduovirus,Ralstonia 25 9 15 NA 100
Hepadnaviridae,Orthohepadnavirus,Hepatitis 45 92 535 NA 492685
```

There is a problem with names having spaces in File2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join` and then `cut` the first field:

```
join <(sort File2) <(sort File1) | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

or just `join` with `-o` and add all fields you wish to be printed:

```
join -o 1.2,1.3,1.4,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6 <(sort File2) <(sort File1)
```

Comment: It's true but my 2 files are much more bigger and have not equal number of rows. Sorry I did not mention that.

Comment: number of rows should not matter, `join` can handle this.

Comment: It works perfect. Sorry for problem. Thx

Answer (score 0):

try

```
awk 'FNR == NR { u=$1 ; $1="" ; F[u]=$0 ; } 
   $1 in F { $(NF +1) = F[$1] ; $1 = "" ; print }'
```

where

- `$1 = ""` will delete (sort of) `$1`'s value.
- `$(NF +1) = F[$1]` append line of file1 at the end of file2

Answer (score 0):

Tested with  below command and it worked fine

```
for i in `cat file2|awk '{print $1}'`; do j=`sed -n '/'$i'/p' file2| awk '{print $2,$3,$4}'`;  sed -i "s/$i/$j/g" file1; done
```

output

```
Siphoviridae,Biseptimavirus,Staphylococcus virus 108PVL 2 NA NA NA NA 
Siphoviridae,,Lactococcus phage bIL311 3 NA NA NA 186 
Siphoviridae,,Lactococcus phage bIL312 9 NA NA NA 107 
Myoviridae,Peduovirus,Ralstonia virus RSA1 25 9 15 NA 100 
Hepadnaviridae,Orthohepadnavirus,Hepatitis B virus 45 92 535 NA 492685
```